# Solving for a variable that's an index of e

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have arrived at the equation

$$0=e^{10b}+e^{-10b}-2.5$$

and was wondering how I would go about calculating $b$.

I was considering using the quadratic formula but I wasn't sure if it would work since one index isn't raised higher than the other.

Comment: Are you familiar with the hyperbolic cosine function?

Comment: Is it maybe $0=e^{10b}+e^{-10b}-2.5$ ?

Comment: No. I'll write about it in my answer.

Comment: $b=\frac{\log 2}{10}$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As $e^{10b}$ is non-zero finite, multiply both sides by $e^{10b}$ to get $$(e^{10b})^2-2.5(e^{10b})+1=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $e^{10b}$

Now solve and take log with respect to $e$

Comment: This is not a quadratic equation.

Comment: @callculus, Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

We start off knowing that
$$e^{10b}+e^{-10b}=2.5$$
$$\frac{e^{10b}+e^{-10b}}{2}=1.25$$
Now we can use the "$\cosh$" function, or the hyperbolic cosine function (or rather, its inverse). Just as a reminder, the hyperbolic cosine function is
$$\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
and its inverse is
$$\cosh^{-1}x=\ln(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1})$$
So if we apply $\cosh^{-1}$ to both sides of your equation, we get
$$10b=\ln(1.25\pm\sqrt{1.25^2-1})$$
$$10b=\ln(1.25\pm0.75)$$
$$b=\frac{\ln(1.25\pm0.75)}{10}$$
$$b=\pm\frac{\ln(2)}{10}$$

Comment: It´s only one of two real solutions.

Comment: Ok, I went back and changed my answer to include both.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute. $0=e^{10b}+e^{-10b}-2.5$

Replace $e^{10b}$ by $x$.

$$0=x+\frac1x-2.5$$

Multplying the equation by x.

$x^2+1-2.5x=0$

$x^2-2.5x+1=0$

Using the quadratic formula to solve it.

$x_{1/2}=\frac{2.5\pm \sqrt{6.25-4}}{2}$

$x_{1/2}=\frac{2.5\pm 1.5}{2}$

$x_1=2, x_2=0.5$

Re-substitution

$$2=e^{10b_1}\Rightarrow \ln(2)=10b_1 \Rightarrow b_1=\frac{\ln(2)}{10}$$

$$0.5=e^{10b_2}\Rightarrow \ln(0.5)=10b_2 \Rightarrow b_2=\frac{-\ln(2)}{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$e^{10b}+e^{-10b}-2.5=0$$

We can multiply both sides by $e^{10b}$ to get

\begin{align}e^{10b}\left(e^{10b}+e^{-10b}-2.5\right)&=e^{10b}\times 0\\
\left(e^{10b}\right)^2+1-2.5e^{10b}&=0\\
\left(e^{10b}\right)^2-2.5e^{10b}+1&=0\end{align}

We use the substitution $t=e^{10b}$ and rewrite this as \begin{align}t^2-2.5t+1&=0\\
\left(t-\frac{2.5}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2.5}{2}\right)^2+1&=0\\
(t-1.25)^2-1.5625+1&=0\\
(t-1.25)^2-0.5625&=0\\
(t-1.25)^2&=0.5625\\
t-1.25&=\pm\sqrt{0.5625}\\
t-1.25&=\pm0.75\\
t&=1.25\pm0.75\\
t&=\{2,0.5\}\end{align}

So now we have to solve $e^{10b}=t$

Firstly, we have \begin{align}e^{10b}&=2\\
\ln\left(e^{10b}\right)&=\ln(2)\\
10b&=\ln(2)\\
b&=\frac{\ln(2)}{10}\end{align}

We also have \begin{align}e^{10b}&=\frac 12\\
\ln\left(e^{10b}\right)&=\ln\left(\frac 12\right)\\
10b&=\ln(1)-\ln(2)\\
10b&=-\ln(2)\\
b&=-\frac{\ln(2)}{10}\end{align}

Therefore we have our answer: $$b=\pm\frac{\ln(2)}{10}$$

---

Note: I am using the following logarithm laws:

\begin{align}\ln\left(e^a\right)&=a\\
\ln\left(\frac ab\right)&=\ln(a)-\ln(b)\end{align}